# Jquery and php IF Else

Tags: jquery

Hey Folks and having some trouble with this statement and could use some help.

```
$('#accept-btn').click(function(){
 $.cookie('is_legal', 'yes', { expires: 1, path: '/', domain: 'domain.com' });

 <?php if ( !isset($_REQUEST['redirect']) || $_REQUEST['redirect'] == "" ) { ?>
 document.location = "http://www.domain.com";

 <?php }else{ ?>
 document.location = "<?php echo $_REQUEST['redirect']; ?>";
 <?php } ?>
});
```

Basically it's age verification, so far it works great when you click on the button, but the else, assuming this is when you click on another item, it is supposed to redirect.

SO the HTML is

```
<p>Are you OVER 18</p>
<div id="accept-btn">YES</div>
<div id="noaccept-btn">     NO</div >
```

Any ideas why the ELSE is not working?

I am trying to implement the method from 
http://www.techerator.com/2010/09/how-to-perform-age-verification-with-jquery-and-cookies-mmm-cookies/

Comment: jQuery is run on the client, PHP is run on the server. It looks as though you do not understand how this will be executed.

Comment: What does the resulting JavaScript code look like client-side?

Comment: @zzzzzBOV hence the question bubba

Comment: To elaborate on ZZZZBov's point, because PHP is run on the server, anything inside a PHP tag is run FAR before any JavaScript runs, and you cannot tell JavaScript to run PHP code.

Comment: ah gotcha. client side, looks like: <script type="text/javascript">
$('#accept-btn').click(function(){
 $.cookie('is_legal', 'yes', { expires: 1, path: '/', domain: '' });
 
  document.location = "";
 
 });
</script>

Comment: http://www.techerator.com/2010/09/how-to-perform-age-verification-with-jquery-and-cookies-mmm-cookies/

Comment: document.location = "<?php echo $_REQUEST['redirect']; ?>";
that's a really nasty line by the way. If someone went to yoursite.com?redirect="; inject javascript here!; " they could run whatever code they want on your site.

Comment: yeah am going to scratch this method, I found it online, so yeah prolly not the best way to do this.